# django two class data in one table how to append

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I want Mvouchar and Mycheque details append in one list that is reports, and field is also the same.

Can I append this in one function? Because in my way it append only Mvouchars value

How can I do this for both?

**views.py**

```
def all_report(request):
        reports = []
        for report_obj in Mvouchar.objects.all():
                reports.append({'topay': report_obj.to_pay, 'chequeno': report_obj.cheque_no, 'chequedate': report_obj.cheque_date, 'date': report_obj.dated})

        return render(request, 'cheque/report.html', {'reports': reports})  

def all_report(request):
        reports = []
        for report_obj in Mycheque.objects.all():
                reports.append({'topay': report_obj.to_pay, 'chequeno': report_obj.cheque_no, 'chequedate': report_obj.cheque_date, 'date': report_obj.dated})

        return render(request, 'Cheque/report.html', {'reports': reports})
```

Comment: You need to provide more detail, we can assume that Mvouchar and Mycheque are your models, but you don't explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def all_report(request):
    reports = []
    for model in (Mvouchar, Mycheque):
        for report in model.objects.all():
            reports.append({'topay': report_obj.to_pay, 'chequeno': report_obj.cheque_no, 'chequedate': report_obj.cheque_date, 'date': report_obj.dated})

    return render(request, 'cheque/report.html', {'reports': reports})
```

Comment: how can i use filter in this list object cheque no from text to text and also search cheque date from text to text search objects from this list and return the filterd list that have searched objects

Comment: Please add description of your models

Comment: hey @vadim Shatalov plz my my models.py below

Comment: i want a filterd list that have the all data of in between searched date and cheque no and save this in list.html where i print this data...plz help this is my first project on django and i try a lot...